# Settings Won't Open Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, system-settings

When I try to open settings by clicking on it, nothing happens, it instantly closes.  When I run "gnome-control-center", I get the following error:

```
(gnome-control-center:62908): Clutter-CRITICAL **: 21:10:22.069: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to initialize the Clutter backend: no available drivers found.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I just want to open settings ...

Comment: Me too! Same problem.

Comment: @Andyc the problem eventually went away for me.  Weird, because I didn't really do anything.  I tried sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo reboot, but that didn't immediately fix it.  Next day it worked,

Comment: That's why I love Ubuntu: it's good brain gymnastics. It keeps you thinking... :D

Comment: The question is a bit old by now, but I encountered similar issues a while back (too far back to remember the exact errors). While I can't tell if it's the same issue here, the settings app wouldn't open for me after updating the nvidia drivers. There was a version mismatch since the old kernel module was still loaded. Should be easy enough to find out if it's something similar by just consulting journalctl.